# one out of two fields is required [PHP]

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form with two fields and one of them is required. Is it possible to do it in php or css?
If no, how can I do it in jQuery so that changing dynamically? For example, before entering some text into one of these two fields  these should be green and if text is entering into one of this fields, both of fields should change a color to white.

This is my code:

```
$oForm->formInput(array(
    'class' =>'myGroup',
    'name' => 'krs',
    'label' => 'KRS',
    'size' => '60',
    'maxlength'=>'70',
    'required' =>checkIfRequired()

));

$oForm->formInput(array(
    'class' =>'myGroup',
    'type' => 'number',
    'name' => 'nrRej',
    'label' => 'nr rejestrowy',
    'size' => '60',
    'maxlength'=>'70'
));

function checkIfRequired(){
    if(empty($_POST['nrRej']))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

$oForm->formSubmit(array(
    'name' => 'generatePdf',
    'value' => 'Wygeneruj pdf',
    'sId' => 'form_add'
));
```

P.S function checkIfRequired doesn't work. 
Can you help me?

Comment: You can use an attribute called required on your html input

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: You can do it both in PHP and jQuery, but i recommend you, to alwas do a server validation also (PHP). See this link: http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: @DavidJones While this is true, it's relying on the client browser to do the enforcement. It's the same problem as JS-only validation. You need to have server side validation which means you check for the proper input and show an error the client can understand.

Comment: @Machavity Your exactly right, I should have clarified that. I saw the checkIfRequired function and assumed he / she was already doing it

Comment: Why vote down? 
I can't post html because it's a part of my library and it's too long and not needed to solve that. $oForm have all arguments.